# Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give all the roots of the given function?

Tags: functions, numerics, numerical-value, equation-solving

I have this equation

$$   36 \cos \frac{3 x}{4}  \cos  \frac{27 x}{20}  \left(\cos  \frac{3 x}{5} +2 \cos  \frac{21 x}{10} \right)=0  $$

> Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give all the roots of the function on the domain $0<x<4\pi$? Preferably as a rational multiple of $\pi$? (the plot of the function is attached)

```
36 Cos[(3 x)/4] Cos[(27 x)/20] (Cos[(3 x)/5] + 2 Cos[(21 x)/10]) == 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sol = x /. Solve[36 Cos[(3 x)/4] Cos[(27 x)/20] (Cos[(3 x)/5] + 2 Cos[(21 x)/10]) == 0&& 0 < x < 4 Pi]

Plot[36 Cos[(3 x)/4] Cos[(27 x)/20] (Cos[(3 x)/5] + 
    2 Cos[(21 x)/10]), {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   Point[Transpose[{sol, ConstantArray[0, Length@sol]}]]}]
```

[image]

[image]

If you desire only roots that are rational multiples of Pi, you can use (among many other ways):

```
Select[sol, #/Pi \[Element] Rationals &]
```

Comment: Thanks, Then, does this mean that those $ArcTan[...]$ are definitely not multiple of $\pi$? Is it correct to use $N[ArcTan ...]$ to know their numerical value?

Comment: @quark - it means they're not *rational* multiples of Pi, and yes, `N` will get you the numeric result.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this doesn't prove that the ArcTan[..] terms are not rational multiples of Pi. They may be.